# Amplify Build Failure, Module not found './aws-exports'

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

Ive seen a few posts about this but ive been unable to find a solution as of yet. Im trying to create a react.js app with an Amplify backend with graphQL, for whatever reason when i try run my Build on AWS Amplify i get the following error.

```
2022-05-31T03:56:26.492Z [INFO]: Creating an optimized production build...
2022-05-31T03:56:27.198Z [INFO]: Failed to compile.
2022-05-31T03:56:27.199Z [INFO]: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './aws-exports' in '/codebuild/output/src520478948/src/my-vet-dental/src'
2022-05-31T03:56:27.210Z [WARNING]: npm
2022-05-31T03:56:27.210Z [WARNING]: ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
                                    npm ERR! errno 1
2022-05-31T03:56:27.212Z [WARNING]: npm
2022-05-31T03:56:27.213Z [WARNING]: ERR! my-vet-dental@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
                                    npm ERR! Exit status 1
                                    npm ERR!
                                    npm ERR! Failed at the my-vet-dental@0.1.0 build script.
                                    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2022-05-31T03:56:27.220Z [WARNING]: 
2022-05-31T03:56:27.220Z [WARNING]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
                                    npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-05-31T03_56_27_213Z-debug.log
2022-05-31T03:56:27.220Z [HELP]: Outputting the npm debug log
                                 [object Promise]
2022-05-31T03:56:27.223Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2022-05-31T03:56:27.223Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
2022-05-31T03:56:27.223Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2022-05-31T03:56:27.224Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
```

How do i fix this issue?